# Partition of unity in $\mathbb{R}$ with additional conditions on the derivatives

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be locally compact without isolated points and $X$ an infinite dimentional Banach space. Then 
$$C_{0}^{(1)}(K,X)=\{ f\in C_{0}(K,X): \text{$f$ is continuously differentiable and} \;f' \in C_{0}(K,X) \}$$

is a banach space considering the norm $\left \Vert f\right \Vert_M=\max \{\left \Vert f\right \Vert_{\infty}, \left \Vert f'\right \Vert_{\infty}\}.$ 
Here $C_{0}(K,X)$ stands for the banach space consisting of all functions that vanish at infinity.

Suppose $\phi\in C_{0}^{(1)}(K,X)$,  $k \in K$ and  consider the set

$$
(*) \quad \quad V_{k}=\left\{ s\in K:\left\Vert \phi(k)-\phi(s)\right\Vert   <\varepsilon \; \text{and} \; \left\Vert \phi'(k)-\phi'(s)\right\Vert  \; <\varepsilon \right\},
$$

then 
$\{V_k:k\in K\}   $ is an open covering of 
$K$. It is a well known fact that partitions of unity subbordinate to 
the cover exists, i.e. there exists smooth 
functions $ \varphi_{k} : V_k \rightarrow [0,1] $ with compact 
support such that 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \varphi_k(x) = 1 \; \text{for all $x\in V_k$} \quad \text{and}  \quad supp \; \varphi_{k} \subseteq V_k \; \text{for all $k \in K$}.$$

My question is the following: By assuming the conditions on $(*)$ is it possible to conclude that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \varphi'_k(x) = 1  \quad \text{and}  \quad supp \; \varphi'_{k} \subseteq V_k \;?$$

where $\varphi'_{k}$ is the derivative of $\varphi_{k}$.
If is not possible ( I dont really know ), is it possible to make more assumptions on the sets $V_t$ (or perhaps $K$) so that can happen?

> EDIT: As pointed out by the comments, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \varphi'_k(x) = 0$
>   So I'll try to give context to what I wanna try to emulate:
>
> Basically I want to check that the set $A=\left\{ \phi\left(\cdot\right)x:\phi\in C_{0}^{(1)}\left(K\right),x\in X\right\} $ is dense in $C_{0}^{(1)}(K,X)$.

We start again with $\{V_k:k\in K\}$ a open cover for $K$, since $K$ is locally compact then there exist $\left\{ W_{t}:t\in K\right\} $ open covering of $K$ such that every $ W_{t}$ is relatively compact. So that there exist functions (with compact support) $\left\{ \varphi_{t}:K\mapsto\mathbb{R}\right\} _{t\in K}$ such that $supp\;\varphi_{t}\subset W_{t}$ for all $t\in K$, then every $\varphi_{t}$ and it's derivative vanish at infinity, i.e $\varphi_{t}\in C_{0}^{(1)}(K,[0,1])$.

> this is the important part: Let $t \in K $ and consider 
>   $$
> g(t)=\sum_{\alpha\in K}\varphi_{\alpha}(t)\phi(t_{\alpha}) 
> $$

( the idea is to conclude $(1) \; \left\Vert \phi(t)-g(t)\right\Vert_{\infty}<\varepsilon $ and $\left\Vert \phi'(t)-g'(t)\right\Vert_{\infty}<\varepsilon$ so that $\left\Vert \phi(t)-g(t)\right\Vert_{M}<\varepsilon $.

This is the $(1)$ part: $ \left\Vert \phi(t)-g(t)\right\Vert_{\infty}<\varepsilon $

\begin{align}
\left\Vert \phi(t)-\sum_{\alpha\in K}\varphi_{\alpha}(t)\phi(t_{\alpha})\right\Vert _{\infty}&=\left\Vert \sum_{\alpha\in K}\left(\varphi_{\alpha}(t)\phi(t)-\varphi_{\alpha}(t)\phi(t_{\alpha})\right)\right\Vert _{\infty}\\&=\left\Vert \sum_{\alpha\in K}\varphi_{\alpha}(t)\left(\phi(t)-\phi(t_{\alpha})\right)\right\Vert _{\infty}\\&\leq\sum_{\alpha\in K}\varphi_{\alpha}(t)\left\Vert \phi(t)-\phi(t_{\alpha})\right\Vert_{\infty} 
\end{align}

Where $\left\Vert \phi(t)-\phi(t_{\alpha})\right\Vert _{\infty}<\varepsilon$.

Now by the help from comments I dont thinkg the part $\left\Vert \phi'(t)-g'(t)\right\Vert_{\infty}<\varepsilon$ is plausible.  Should I construct a new function $g$?  Is there a easier way to check that $A$ (the closed linear subspace) is dense?

Comment: Don't you need some regularity assumption on $f$ to belong to your space $^{(1)}_0(,)$, like being $C^1$ or smooth ?

Comment: Yea.  All $f$ in that space are $C^1$. I'll  fix it.

Comment: (1) If the support of $\varphi_k$ is contained in $V_k$, then isn't the support of $\varphi_k'$ trivially contained in $V_k$ as well?  (2) Intuitively, if $\sum \varphi_k = 1$, shouldn't we expect $\sum \varphi_k' = 0$ (e.g. if we could commute the derivative with the infinite sum) instead of 1?

Comment: You are right! I was trying to emulate a inequlity from the $\varphi_k$ to $\varphi'_k$ .  I guess I have to work on it a little more.